# Aiogram sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Всем доброго времени суток, я столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно чтобы пользователи из бд были в кнопках, я выводил циклом но была либо пользователя под индексом 0 либо 1

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="menu") 
async def cmd_random(msg: types.Message): 
    data = await get_user2(msg) 
    for el in data: 
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=str(el),
            callback_data="random_value"))
    await msg.answer("кого кикнуть?", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Нормально обьясните, ничего не понятно

Comment: Смотрите, есть база данных, я хочу вывести из базы данных, username всех пользователей и при нажатии удалять их

Comment: В  inline кнопки вывести

Comment: Ну так проверьте что у вас в дате лежит, нам то откуда знать как выглядит ваша бд

Comment: Дата такая async def get_user2(msg: types.Message):
    conn=sql.connect('usersBot.db')
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    user = msg.from_user
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM users")
# Select это выбор каких либо данных 
    data = cursor.fetchall()
#fetchone это выбор одного элемента 
    return data

Comment: Не добавляйте это в комментариях, просто исправьте вопрос. Я имею ввиду, что именно у вас в бд, просто пропринтуйте ее

Comment: Простите, я не особо понял вас

Comment: Под вашим вопросом есть кнопка Править, просто добавьте код туда. А насчет пропринтовать это сделать вы первых `print(data)` во вторых `print(el)`

Comment: Вы не так поняли, из бд выводиться только. 1 юзер нэйм, а я хочу сделать чтобы выводились все, но он выводит либо массив либо 1 елемент при этом у меня цикл for el in data который выберает всё из username

Comment: Ну так а вы уверены что в таблице есть что-то ещё? Я то и говорю принтаните дату

Comment: Я выводил, он выдает всех пользователей, их у меня 2 штуки, я и тестовый аккаунт, когда делаю принт, он дает 2, а когда я передаю в массив где кнопки он дает либо меня либо тестовый

Answer (score 0):

Вы маркап выведите из цикла, а то он постоянно создается с нуля

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="menu") 
async def cmd_random(msg: types.Message): 
    data = await get_user2(msg) 
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for el in data: 
        keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=str(el),
            callback_data="random_value"))
    await msg.answer("кого кикнуть?", reply_markup=keyboard)
```